# How can I wait on multiple values with C++20 atomic wait?

Tags: c++, concurrency, synchronization, c++20, stdatomic

C++20 provides atomic wait to wait until the value changes. One thing we can do is replace condition variable with atomic wait. For example,

```cpp
bool has_tasks{true};
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;

{
  std::uniqe_lock lock{mtx};
  // unblock if has_tasks is false
  cv.wait(lock, [](){ return !has_tasks; }) // someone will notify
  // ...
}

// equivalent
std::atomic<bool> has_tasks{true};
// unblock if has_tasks is false
has_tasks.wait(true); // someone will notify
// ...
```

A thread will be blocked until has_tasks becomes false and the thread gets notified;

However, what if I want to wait on all values except one value? By using condition variable, I can do:

```cpp
size_t num_tasks{0};
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;
std::uniqe_lock lock{mtx};
{
 cv.wait(lock, [](){ return num_tasks == 0; })
}

// equivalent
std::atomic<size_t> num_tasks{0};
num_tasks.wait(/* how to wait on multiple values? */)
```

A thread will only be unblocked if num_tasks is zero.
Is there any way to replace above condition variable with atomic wait?

Comment: make it a `std::atmoic<bool>` again that the writer threads sets to `true` when the condition is met

Comment: With `wait` directly, only by rolling your own spin-wait, or by using features of the OS-specific APIs that `.wait()` doesn't expose.  e.g. on Linux, the initial version of `futex()` ([man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html)) only supported compare for equal, but Linux 2.6.25 (in 2008) added `FUTEX_WAKE_BITSET`.  I don't know how `.wait()` is implemented on other OSes, and if the functionality it exposes really is the only lowest-common-denominator that can be done portably and efficiently.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The tricky part is if I use another atomic bool, I cannot guarantee whether the condition is still met after I change the atomic bool

Comment: If @463035818_is_not_a_number's suggestion works, that might be viable. Waiters can wait on that, and investigate the situation after being woken.  (And notifiers can themselves investigate the situation to figure out whether to send a notify).  If you were hoping to have each waiter waiting on a different condition, and the notify only waking the one whose condition is now true, that's harder.  You only have `.notify_one` or `.notify_all`.

Comment: @user13177419 but this you cannot anyhow. Also in your first example `has_tasks.wait(true);` waits for `true`, then returns, but in the next moment the value can be `false` again

Comment: @user13177419 btw I was just stating the obvious. I think your example is not the best, because "A thread will only be unblocked if num_tasks is zero." can be easily modeled via a `std::atmoic<bool>`, though other more complex conditions, possibly depending on writes of different threads, cannot

Comment: @user13177419: You always have to check for spurious wake-ups, if another thread could have already claimed the task you were looking for.  So I'm not sure that's a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot wait for two independent events using a single call to atomic wait. But, you can wait twice (or `n` times) to achieve the same effect.

The following code waits for `num_tasks` to be incremented twice (or set to something other than `0` or `1`) before the thread is allowed to complete. With `std::atomic`, you do not need to check for spurious wake-ups as that is handled by the `std::atomic` which simplifies the logic a bit.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    std::atomic<int> num_tasks{};

    auto th = std::thread([&]() {
        cout << "waiting on tasks" << endl;
        num_tasks.wait(0);
        cout << "one task ready" << endl;
        num_tasks.wait(1);
        cout << "two tasks ready" << endl;
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
    cout << "adding task" << endl;
    num_tasks = num_tasks + 1;
    num_tasks.notify_one();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
    cout << "adding task" << endl;
    num_tasks = num_tasks + 1;
    num_tasks.notify_one();

    if (th.joinable())
        th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
waiting on tasks
adding task
one task ready
adding task
two tasks ready
```

Comment: If you had a thread that's only going to do anything once there are 2 tasks ready, it's very wasteful an inefficient to wake it up an extra time just so it can go to sleep again.  An extra boolean and/or some extra logic in the notifier would make more sense, to decide whether to notify any waiters.  This seems like an anti-pattern for waiting for `num_tasks > 1`.  Also, if anything else is ever decrementing `num_tasks`, a return from `.wait(1)` doesn't mean `2`, it could be back to `0`. Or it could be any higher value; only if you know it's monotonic can you be sure it was `2` at *some* point

Comment: Worse than that, I didn't even answer the question. I think I got this answer mixed up with the two hydrogens, one oxygen question.